# How do I find the work done by the spring the following question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Two bars connected by a weightless spring of stiffness x
and length (in the non-deformed state) L[image] rest on a horizontal plane.
A constant horizontal force F starts acting on one of the bars as shown
in Fig. 1.40. Find the maximum and minimum distances between the
bars during the subsequent motion of the system.

This is Q 1.152 of "Problems in General Physics" by IE Irodov.

How do I calculate the total work done by the spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power that goes through the spring at any point is defined by

$$ P = F_{\rm spring}\cdot ( v_2-v_1 ) $$

where $F_{\rm spring} =-x\, (p_2-p_1-L) $ is the spring force and $v_1$, $v_2$ are the velocities of the two masses located at $p_1$ and $p_2$.

If you have worked out the problem, you know the form of $v_1(t)$ and $v_2(t)$ and to get the total work done is a simple integral

$$ W = \int P {\rm d}t = \int F_{\rm spring}\cdot ( v_2-v_1 ) {\rm d}t $$